# how do I access the SPDIF signal from my phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

my galaxy s has the option to have 5.1 surround enabled. what plug on my phone produces the digital audio signal to carry the 5.1 surround?
is this option only available through bluetooth or can it be used through the headphone port or USB port?

Answer (score 1):

The Samsing Galaxy S series has a **virtual** surround, not a true surround. Therefore there is no way to get multichannel audio out of the device, only analog stereo.

Source: [Phandroid](http://phandroid.com/2010/08/27/srs-5-1-virtual-surround-sound-in-all-galaxy-s-phones/), [Unleashthephones](http://unleashthephones.com/2010/08/29/samsung-galaxy-s-series-feature-a-rocking-srs-5-1-virtual-surround-sound/), [Intomobile](http://www.intomobile.com/2010/08/27/samsung-galaxy-s-smartphones-rock-srs-5-1-virtual-surround-sound/)